# Eclipse with Roku plugin: editor unusably slow

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna, roku, eclipse-neon

Eclipse editor taking too much time or hanging when any action perform like save or copy, paste..
I am working on Roku platform with bright-scripts.
i3 system 8GB RAM

Comment: Eclipse IDE actually has many editors (almost one for each language). Does this happen for every file/editor? Did you install some 3rd party plugins that could mess up the IDE. Also, you should consider seriously using Eclipse Neon which has received a lot of performance improvements compared to Luna.

Comment: No..Only brightscripts file & only eclipse (luna,mars,neon)editor ..Can I use another editor for same. Which editor should i use?

Answer (score 0):

Roku's plugin for Eclupse is a known troublemaker.

Don't use eclipse for Roku - any other, lightweight developer editor (with syntax highlighter for VB, VBScript or BASIC - and optionally XML) will do fine.

On Mac, currently i use TextWrangler. 
Plus small script to ZIP the bundle. There is not much to the build process for Roku really. 
And the debugger is command line, hence telnet to Roku.